# Equidistribution of spheres in $\mathbb{R^2}/\mathbb{Z^2}$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, homogeneous-spaces

Let $\mathbb{H^2}$ be the hyperbolic upper half place, and let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting on $\mathbb{H^2}$. A proof of the equidistribution of spheres on $\mathbb{H^2/\Gamma}$  as their radii grow can be found in "Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces" by Bekka and Meyer. I have been told that this is also true of spheres in $\mathbb{R^2/Z^2}$ but I can't see how to prove this nor find a reference that does. Can anyone see why it is true or know of a reference?

Comment: A large circle can be approximated by medium length straight lines oriented in various directions, most of which will be badly approximable by rationals of small denominator and thus will equidistribute over the 2-torus at a some reasonably coarse scale.  One basically has to keep track of quantitative error terms in all of the above assertions and choose parameters carefully in order to turn this into a rigorous argument.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use the Weyl equidistribution criterion to reduce matters to establishing non-trivial cancellation for a certain family of oscillatory integrals, which one can accomplish for instance using van der Corput estimates.

Comment: In addition to Terry's answer, a more general result was achieved by Randol (building upon much earlier works, maybe Herz? Stein?) in "THE BEHAVIOR UNDER PROJECTION OF DILATING SETS IN A COVERING SPACE", this article also have the spherical result you've mentioned (by means of a pre-trace formula, essentially point-pair invariance analysis), as far as I know, this result is not discussed in Bekka's book (which deals with horocyclic flows, not spheres, as spheres are not amenable to Dani/Ratner's theorems).

Comment: Is there some reason why Eskin/McMullen's approach does not just work in this case?

Comment: @IgorRivin Maybe I do not understand the vocabulary correctly, but the set-up there is "Let G be a connected semisimple Lie group with finite center, and let H ⊂ G be a closed subgroup such that G/H is an affine symmetric space," which would not apply here since the isometry group of $\mathbb{R^2}$ does not have a finite center?

Comment: @A.Shah Yes, I know, but my feeling is that the methods work even easier in the abelian case (granted, I haven't gone through it...)

Comment: @IgorRivin, from Eskin-McMullen you can deduce equidistribution of "translated" spheres, as the center tends to infinity (this actually already follows from Margulis, as the translation of the center + dilation ammounts to conjugation by Cartan element). Nimish Shah have generalized such an approach (see for example - "Limiting distributions of curves under geodesic flow on hyperbolic manifold."). If you want to keep your center fixed, this is much harder and delicate.

Comment: @IgorRivin, for the toral case, the action is not mixing...